# Overflow error when using the sum function?

Tags: sql, db2

I'm writing a query to calculate how much more the average customer has transacted and spent since signing up with my company. However, it returns the error message "Overflow occurred during numeric data type conversion".

The problem is definitely this bit, as when I comment it out the query runs successfully:

```
SUM(SALES_GROWTH_PERCENT)
```

Google tells me it's likely that I'm trying to fit a number with too many decimal places into a field that's too short for it. However, I've tried changing how many decimal places the case statements are using with no luck.

Edit: for context, here are the details of the fields being used, from syscat.columns:

[image]

This is the query in question. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong please? Any advice would be appreciated!

```
SELECT  SUM(TRANS_GROWTH_PERCENT)/COUNT(CUSTOMER_ID) AS AVG_TRANS_GROWTH_PERCENT,
        SUM(SALES_GROWTH_PERCENT)/COUNT(CUSTOMER_ID) AS AVG_SALES_GROWTH_PERCENT    
FROM
        (
        SELECT  CUSTOMER_ID,
                CASE    WHEN POST_SIGNUP_TRANS <=0
                        THEN 0  
                        WHEN POST_SIGNUP_TRANS >0 
                        THEN CAST((CAST(POST_SIGNUP_TRANS AS DECIMAL (10,5)) - CAST(PRE_SIGNUP_TRANS AS DECIMAL (10,5))) / CAST(PRE_SIGNUP_TRANS AS DECIMAL (10,5)) * 100 AS DECIMAL (10,1))    
                        ELSE NULL 
                        END AS TRANS_GROWTH_PERCENT,
                CASE    WHEN POST_SIGNUP_SALES <=0 
                        THEN 0
                        WHEN POST_SIGNUP_SALES >0
                        THEN CAST((CAST(POST_SIGNUP_SALES AS DECIMAL (10,5)) - CAST(PRE_SIGNUP_SALES AS DECIMAL (10,5))) / CAST(PRE_SIGNUP_SALES AS DECIMAL (10,5)) * 100 AS DECIMAL (10,1))
                        ELSE NULL
                        END AS SALES_GROWTH_PERCENT
        FROM
                (
                SELECT      CUSTOMER_ID, 
                            SUM(PRE_SIGNUP_TRANS) AS PRE_SIGNUP_TRANS, SUM(PRE_SIGNUP_SALES) AS PRE_SIGNUP_SALES,
                            SUM(POST_SIGNUP_TRANS) AS POST_SIGNUP_TRANS, SUM(POST_SIGNUP_SALES) AS POST_SIGNUP_SALES
                FROM
                            (
                            SELECT  CUSTOMER_ID,
                                    CASE WHEN TRANSACTION_DATE >= ANALYSIS_START_DATE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ANALYSIS_FLAG,
                                    CASE WHEN TRANSACTION_DATE < SIGNUP_DATE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS PRE_SIGNUP_TRANS,
                                    CASE WHEN TRANSACTION_DATE < SIGNUP_DATE THEN SALES ELSE 0 END AS PRE_SIGNUP_SALES,
                                    CASE WHEN TRANSACTION_DATE >= SIGNUP_DATE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS POST_SIGNUP_TRANS,
                                    CASE WHEN TRANSACTION_DATE >= SIGNUP_DATE THEN SALES ELSE 0 END AS POST_SIGNUP_SALES
                            FROM    TRANSACTIONS_TABLE
                            )
                WHERE       ANALYSIS_FLAG = 1
                GROUP BY    CUSTOMER_ID
                )
        WHERE   PRE_SIGNUP_TRANS >0
        AND     PRE_SIGNUP_SALES >0
        )       
;
```

Comment: What are the table definitions including data types? What Db2 platform and version?

Comment: @data_henrik I've added the data types to the original post. Unfortunately I don't know what db2 platform or version.

Comment: Try `DEC (DEC (100 * (POST_SIGNUP_[TRANS | SALES] - PRE_SIGNUP_[TRANS | SALES]), 30) / PRE_SIGNUP_xxx, 12, 1)` for the `[TRANS | SALES]_GROWTH_PERCENT` columns instead.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Do you mean to use your code into the case when statement? I tried this but got the error message "a decimal divide operation is not valid because the result would have a negative scale".

Comment: @SRJCoding Here is a [dbfiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=5c5d1bc70c0e5ea11e6919f4cec4d11b) with what I suggested to do. There is no such error on my SELECT statement.